# Why is the deposition of silver more uniform from [Ag(Cl)₂]⁻ (aq) than from Ag⁺?

Tags: electrochemistry

What determines the uniformity? Just a fun fact I am wondering about, because I saw cyanide solutions used in electroplating.

Answer (score 3):

The uniformity of a deposition depends on more parameters, but in this case the difference is in electromigration effect. $\ce{Ag+}$ ions are atrracted to the electrode surface, but the complex $\ce{[Ag(Cl)2]-}$ is repulsed. Cyanides form  complexes as well: $\ce{[Ag(CN)2]-}$ or $\ce{[Ag(Cl)3]2-}$ and they are also  repulsed.

Silver electrodepostion form $\ce{AgNO3}$ ($\ce{Ag+}$ in solution) is without additives nearly impossible as dendrites are created. [Fukunaka, Yamamoto, Kondo, Ionic Mass Transfer Associated with Dendrite Growth of Electrodeposited Silver in AgNO3 Solution, 1989 ECS](http://jes.ecsdl.org/content/136/12/3630.short).

The metal deposition from a complex molecules is described in [Wilkinson, P. Understanding Gold Plating. Gold Bull 1986, 19, 75 – 81](http://download-v2.springer.com/static/pdf/792/art%253A10.1007%252FBF03214646.pdf?token2=exp=1428667646~acl=%2Fstatic%2Fpdf%2F792%2Fart%25253A10.1007%25252FBF03214646.pdf*~hmac=ccf7fe61d2a2f3c0f23901bea800b58510b102e53e8f19184252f0f01c766b60)

[image: deposition form complex]

Some chemicals, that are usually added to electrolyte, affect the deposition because they create a film as they are adsorbed at  inner Helmholz plane. (E.g. acidic Cu deposition with alcohol addition [Popescu et al, Materials Chemistry and Physics 72 (2001) 332–336](https://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fprofile%2FLiana_Muresan%2Fpublication%2F222671572_Kinetic_and_morphological_investigation_of_copper_electrodeposition_from_sulfate_electrolytes_in_the_presence_of_an_additive_based_on_ethoxyacetic_alcohol_and_triethyl-benzyl-ammonium_chloride%2Flinks%2F0912f50755620272bc000000.pdf&ei=QrsnVauhHImRsAHkm4ToDg&usg=AFQjCNE8M66i286S2pS67US7k32jV9bLVg&sig2=Rrbgwrp2EZxdIVVnv1AXFw&bvm=bv.90491159,d.ZWU&cad=rja).)