How does complex formation help in uniform deposition during electroplating?
Question 17 on the National Standard Examination in Chemistry (2003-04), India, asks:

In the gold plating process, sodium cyanide solution is used as an electrolyte instead of nitric acid, because:

Cyanide forms a complex with gold and thus helps uniform deposition
Sodium cyanide is a better solvent for gold ions
Cyanide binds with impurity ions and keeps the impurities in solution
Deposition of gold from nitric acid is slow


The answer key lists option 1 as correct, which I sort of figured out myself by eliminating the 2 and 3, and recalling the role of cyanide in metallurgy of gold (specifically, cyanide leaching). However, what intrigues me is how the formation of a complex, $\ce{[Au(CN)2]^-}$, leads to uniform deposition.
TLDR: Why wouldn't free gold cations deposit uniformly in the first place?

Edit: I think parts of my queries are answered in https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/28498/145300.

The key is keeping deposition driven by reaction kinetics, not by diffusion.

@Poutnik can you expand on that a bit?
